# Chrome Extension: Issue with passing a parameter

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This is working:

```
function click(e) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: 'var money = 1;'
    }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'peace.js'});
    });
}
```

This is not (edited the code for ease):

```
function click(e) {

    var test = 'test';
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: 'var money = ' + test + ';'
    }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'peace.js'});
    });
}
```

How can I pass it correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the error that you're seeing?

Comment: it says undefined, @jianweichuah

Comment: Have you tried looking into what `e` is? Add `console.log(e)` into the function and see what it is.

Comment: yes, when i console.log it, it shows correctly. just not passing to `peace.js`

Comment: I think this is just injecting the js code into the page, not passing it over to `peace.js`. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript How does `var money = 1;` work?

Comment: @jianweichuah, it is passing when I do it like the first time, but it is not passing when I do it as second time. When I `console.log(e.target.id)`, it works well.

Comment: @jianweichuah, edited. Please see. Thanks!

Comment: How did you verify that `var money = 1;` was correctly passed over to peace.js? Did you read the value from there?

Comment: Yes. And it alerted me '1' as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```
if (e.target.id == 'test1') {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: 'var money = 1'
    }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'peace.js'});
    });
} else  if (e.target.id == 'test2') {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: 'var money = 2'
    }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'test.js'});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the string value is not formatted correctly. For example,

```
function click(e) {
    var test = 'test';
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: 'var money = ' + test + ';'
    }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'peace.js'});
    });
}
```

Wouldn't work because when `var money=test;` is executed, the script doesn't know what `test` is.

If you wanna pass a string over, it should be

```
function click(e) {

    var test = 'test';
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: 'var money = "' + test + '";'
    }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'peace.js'});
    });
}
```

This way, the executed code will be `var money="test";`

Comment: The portable way is to do a JSON encode. See duplicate.